# Update innerquery result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query and a result as follows.
In the database NULL and 0 represent the same meaning.
Now I want a counter based on Null+0 or 1

Eg:in the following example I want the result like this:

```
IsVirtual   Category    counter
NULL+0      3           343+8 = (351 is Total)
```

**Query**

```
select * from 
(
    Select IsVirtual, Category, count(*) as counter
    from [Hardware]
    group by IsVirtual, Category
) innercat
```

Output

```
+-----------+----------+---------+
| IsVirtual | Category | counter |
+-----------+----------+---------+
| NULL      |  3       |    343  |
| 0         |  3       |    8    |
| 1         |  2       |    1    |
| 0         |  1       |    1    |
| NULL      |  6       |    119  |
| 0         |  4       |    1    |
| NULL      |  1       |    70   |
| 0         |  5       |    9    |
| NULL      |  4       |    54   |
| 0         |  2       |    2    |
| NULL      |  5       |    41   |
| NULL      |  2       |    112  |
| 1         |  1       |    5    |
+-----------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this :

```
SELECT COALESCE(IsVirtual, 0) as [IsVirtual],
       Category,
       Count(*) as [Counter]
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY COALESCE(IsVirtual, 0),Category
```

This will give you expected result without using subquery.

Comment: Your query gives counter based on group by category
i want to treat Null as zero in group by.
that means for follwing eg:
For Category 1 counter based whree isvirtual is NUll or Zero and Counter where isvirtual is 1

Comment: That means i wanto merge the NUll and Zero

Comment: Thanks a lot brother..
Thats what i was exctly looking...Thank u

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
select * from (

Select CASE ISNULL(IsVirtual,0)
WHEN 0 Then 'NULL + 0'
ELSE IsVirtual
END AS IsVirtual, Category, count(*) as counter from [Hardware] group by ISNULL(IsVirtual,0), Category

)innercat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same thing by using `MAX` function

This might help you.

```
SELECT 
       max(IsVirtual) as IsVirtual,
       Category,
       Count(*) as Counter
FROM   
       yourtable
GROUP  BY 
       Category
```